# 401 ERROR downloading github package with maven

Tags: java, maven, github, minecraft, unauthorized

Im trying to import a github package for a java program and I'm getting a 401 error.
I have set up setting.xml (/.m2/) with my github username and password.
code:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>github_username</username>
      <password>github_password(also tryed PAT)</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft</url>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Heres my errors on mvn install

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for 'me.homepenguin:hpmovecraft:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for net.countercraft:movecraft:jar is either LATEST or RELEASE (both of them are being deprecated) @ line 76, column 22
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------< me.homepenguin:hpmovecraft >----------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hpmovecraft 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------[ jar ]----------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Version not locked for default bindings plugins [maven-resources-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-jar-plugin, maven-install-plugin], you should define versions in pluginManagement section of your pom.xml or parent
Downloading from github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft/com/ticxo/PlayerAnimator/R1.2.6/PlayerAnimator-R1.2.6.pom
Downloading from github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft/org/spigotmc/spigot-api/1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
[WARNING] org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml failed to transfer from https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of github has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
Downloading from github: https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft/net/countercraft/movecraft/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata net.countercraft:movecraft/maven-metadata.xml from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401)
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.650 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-09T22:53:28-04:00
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hpmovecraft: Could not resolve dependencies for project me.homepenguin:hpmovecraft:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.oraxen:oraxen:jar:1.156.2 -> com.ticxo:PlayerAnimator:jar:R1.2.6: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ticxo:PlayerAnimator:jar:R1.2.6: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.ticxo:PlayerAnimator:pom:R1.2.6 (absent): Could not transfer artifact com.ticxo:PlayerAnimator:pom:R1.2.6 from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft): status code: 401, reason phrase: Unauthorized (401) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the '-e' switch
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the '-X' switch to enable verbose output
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Ive tried putting settings.xml in (/.m2/repository) and (/.m2), cross referencing example code and documentation. Asking other developers with the errors.
I just need to get the github package into my maven library, im not sure where I went wrong with my code.
Also where was I meant to code settings.xml if it was in the wrong place and what were the issues in my code that caused the error?
Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code and other efforts in the question itself. It will help you to find an answer quickly.

Comment: I did post my code, its the mcpaste links,
Im trying to make a Minecraft plugin and need to import an API from a Github package and I'm getting a 401 error and I'm not sure where I messed up in my settings.xml code which is linked above.
Code: https://mcpaste.io/5db3c9f30b0e55b9
Error: https://mcpaste.io/fe04e3b8375838f3

Comment: On Stackoverflow, we expect the code and the error messages to be pasted directly into the question, in code blocks, rather than using external links. The site offers all for formatting utilities required to render it perfectly legibly here, inline in the question.

Comment: Ah ok I see, should be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Could you check whether you can download the package manually? You can use the curl command in the format of `curl https://_:<GITHUB_TOKEN>@maven.pkg.github.com/<REPO_ORGANIZATION>/<REPO_NAME>/<ARTIFACT_GROUP_ID_SEPERATED_WITH_SLASH><ARTIFACT_ID>/<ARTIFACT_VERSION>/<ARTIFACT_NAME> -L --output my.jar`

Comment: I ran it and this is what I got.

`% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
user@computer hpmovecraft %`



And this is the command I ran
`curl https://maven.pkg.github.com/APDevTeam/Movecraft/net.countercraft/movecraft-api%3E/8.0.0_beta-1 -L --output my.jar`